# How to convert iso 8859 string to UTF8 in a postgresql 12 database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

EDIT :

I think I was not clear, I am sorry for that :
I have a column with bytea data. This column, when I apply encode(column,'escape') to it, I got text in the iso8859-1 encoding. I would like to change this text to UTF-8 encoding.

However, when I use the convert function :

> SELECT convert(encode(column,'escape'),'LATIN1','UTF8') FROM table

I got the error : function convert(text, unknown, unknown) does not exist.

I am currently stuck at this point.

Previous question :
When I call convert(encode(column,'escape'
When I do:

```
select encode(name_of_column, 'escape') 
from my_table;
```

I get a varchar encoded in iso88591 instead of UTF-8. I use Postgresql 12. I cannot find a convert function like Oracle convert function for this Postgresql version.

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As iso8859-1 is also called Latin 1, you can use `convert`

> ```
> SELECT convert( 'text_in_Latin 1 or so8859-1 ',  'LATIN1','UTF8')
> ```
>
> ```
> | convert                                                    |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------- |
> | \x746578745f696e5f4c6174696e2031206f7220736f383835392d3120 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a74f1301b6f6c87c70ead846383509ea)*

Comment: I got an error : function convert(text, unknown, unknown) does not exist. The column is a bytea so I first cast it to text then apply your function, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: that is impossible as posgres 12 supports it with addons see if you can reproduce it here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a74f1301b6f6c87c70ead846383509ea

Comment: Yes : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4105eb38a73aebda6344889498dabcc6